# Can you add a pre-populated form with just React Bootstrap and without using 'value' or 'defaultValue'?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

a very basic and probably stupid question.
I have been trying to add a pre existing value into my form without having to change the value attribute itself as I don't want to necessarily set anything as the value I just want to display it in the input box itself so the user can end up editing the value.
Is that possible just using react bootstrap?
For example if I had this code and wanted to add a pre-existing value in the input box.-

```
      <Form.Group controlId="formBasicName">
        <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          name="leadName"
          value={state.leadName}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "leadName")}
        />
      </Form.Group>
```

I have searched this up but could not find anything that could answer this specific question.And I only found an example using formik in the docs itself which was with intial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `value` take a state and give your initial value for your state, in your `onChange` set this state with new user entries then it should work